# Show Ticker option completely missing

Tags: facebook

On my Facebook account (Desktop Browser) I have a right hand sidebar with online friends I can chat with, and above that, a window with friend's activities, obviously called a Ticker. On the bottom of that sidebar there is a gear, with an option Hide Ticker and Show Ticker, which hides that Friends Activity part of the sidebar, or shows it.

[image]

Now, on my friend's account, this option is missing completely, you can't even click-hold and drag the sidebar down in order to reveal the Ticker/Friends activity, and I have no idea why is this.

[image]

Anyone knows how I can bring that option on?